# How to add an image to nodes?

Tags: 7, media

I created a new content type (*Image*), which has an image upload field set. Now I can upload images and they are now nodes. But what do I need to do to add them to other existing content types?

My guess was to turn the image content type into a block. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "but what do I need to do to add them to other existing content types" . You need to duplicate an existing content?

Comment: Well I am trying to put a picture on top of a webform. So I am assuming I need to turn the image into a block in order to do that.

Comment: So you need to display a set of images of already created contents, right?

Comment: Well not a set of images, just 1 image. I think what i need to do is actually add the image field to the webform content type, instead of trying to tack on 1 content type on top of another content type. Would this be correct?

Comment: This 1 image is the same for the webform?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: You can load the node and its image via `node_load` or you can use `views` module or simple use `<img` tag if the image is fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My guess was to turn the image content type into a block, and if so, whats the best module to do that?

## [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean)

> Bean is an acronym that stands for Block Entities Aren't Nodes.
>
> This is a great introductory article about what the bean module.
>
> What is Bean? Think of a Bean as a method to provide new types
> (compared to node this would be a content type) which then provides an
> add content interface to create as many blocks as you require (see
> screenshot below). The bean content can then be placed around the site
> just like any other block.
>
> Beans were driven by the API first. This means that you can create
> block types (bean types) all in a plugin class turning off the UI. The
> entire configuration in code. No worry about feature reverts.

Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9KI6m_UVgU)

**Basically it lets you add fields to blocks.** This module comes with Drupal 8 core by default.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have an image content type to upload images and use them in your other content types.

Simply add an image field to your content type and you are good to go. Basically, at uploading an image, its url will appear, and you can then use that url in an  in the body of your node.

*But there is another way.*

You can also use the modules [imce](https://drupal.org/project/imce),[plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload),[imce_plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_plupload) combined with ckeditor or wysiwyw editor. After correct configuration you will be able to upload images and to manage them with the imce file browser.
Doing so, your content type doesn't need image field anymore, as part of its structure.

I advise you to carefully read the README files if going that second method, because making all of those work correctly need the correct setup, explained in the documentation. It's not click enable and go.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you need is [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

By (1) adding an entityreference field to your webform content type you will be able to attach-link your "Photo" nodes to webform nodes. (2) From the "Manage display" you may adjust the field's position and set its format as "Rendered entity".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are misleading. What you need is exactly [File Entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, which enables to add fields to file fields.

> File entity provides interfaces for managing files. It also extends the core file entity, allowing files to be fieldable, grouped into types, viewed (using display modes) and formatted using field formatters. File entity integrates with a number of modules, exposing files to Views, Entity API, Token and more.